# copy conditional formatting into outlook mail body using c#

Tags: c#, excel

I have this excel range filled with numerical values.
Then I applied color scale of conditional formatting on this range.

Objective is to paste this range with values and color format in an outlook mail body.

I have pasted formatted data in outlook body before where I have set the cell background color beforehand.

In this case, the color changes according to the values. And when I tried retrieving the color code, it gives white color in decimal value.

In the below table, the cell color changes automatically if the value changes.

[image]

Here is my code so far:

```
body += "<table border='1' bordercolor='solid black'>";
                for (int i = 1; i <= lastRow; i++)
                {
                    string bgcolor = "", fontcolor = "";

                    if (i == 1)
                    {
                        bgcolor = "#333399";    //blue
                        fontcolor = "#FFFFFF";  //white
                    }

                    body += "<tr>";
                    for (int j = 1; j <= lastCol; j++)
                    {
                        string val = wsht.Cells[i, j].Text.ToString();

                        if (i != 1)
                        {
                            var color = wsht.Cells[i, j].Interior.Color;        //this does not give the actual color
                            Console.WriteLine(color);
                            body += "<td align='center' bgcolor='" + color + "' width='10%'><font color='" + fontcolor + "' face='Calibri'><b>" + val + "</b></font></td>";
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            body += "<td align='center' bgcolor='" + bgcolor + "' width='10%'><font color='" + fontcolor + "' face='Calibri'><b>" + val + "</b></font></td>";
                        }
                    }
                    body += "</tr>";
                }
                body += "</table><br/>";
```

Please help to get the right color from excel cell using c#.

Any other solution to achieve the same will be appreciated.

Comment: Use the [ColorTranslator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.colortranslator.tohtml?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1#System_Drawing_ColorTranslator_ToHtml_System_Drawing_Color_) to translate the colors from and to HTML colors. Also use the [StringBuilder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.stringbuilder?view=netcore-3.1) to create the `body` instead of the string concatenation.

Comment: Hi...thank you for replying...the ColorTranslator is not capturing the cell color which is based on condition. It always returns white and there lies my problem.